# method - keep going

Tags: java, loops, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InteractiveRectangle
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    do 
    { 
        int length = readInteger ("For Length ");
        System.out.println();
        int width = readInteger ("For Width ");
        printRectangleDetails(length,width);// existing code goes here 
    } 
    while (keepGoing()); 

    System.out.println("Goodbye, friend"); 
}


/**
 * returns the details of the rectangle
 * @param height the height of the rectangle
 * @param width the width of the rectangle
 */
public static void printRectangleDetails (int length, int width)
{
    System.out.println ("This is the length of the rectangle " + length);

    System.out.println ("This is the width of the rectangle " + width);

    System.out.println (("This is the perimeter of the rectangle " + (length + width)));

    System.out.println (("This is the area of the rectangle " + (length * width)));
}

/**
 * Read in an integer and return its value
 * @param the prompt to be shown to the user
 */
public static int readInteger(String prompt)
{
    System.out.println (prompt);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");

    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) // while non-integers are present
    {
        scan.next();
        System.out.println ("Bad input. Enter an integer.");
    }
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    return input;
}

/**
 * Read a positive integer and return its value
 * @param the prompt to be shown to the user
 */
public static int readPositiveInteger(String prompt)
{
    System.out.println (prompt);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    boolean positive = false;

    while (scan.hasNextInt() && positive == false)
    {
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        if (input > 0)
        {
            positive = true;
            {
                return input;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println ("Bad input enter an integer.");
            positive = false;
            scan.nextLine();

        }

    }
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Ask the user whether or not to spawn another rectangle
 * and returns the result as a boolean
 */
public static boolean keepGoing()    
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean inputRead = false;
    boolean result = false;
    System.out.println ("Do you want to process another rectangle?"); 
    scan.next();
    String input = scan.next();

    if (input == "y")
    {
        inputRead = true;
        result = true;

    }
    else if (input == "n")
    {
        inputRead = true;
        result = false;

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Bad input please try again!");
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    return result;

}
```

}

I want the program to ask the user if they want to spawn another rectangle, and keep going until the user answers this question with “n”. Atm when I run the program, the rectangle only spawns once, so I think there's a problem with my keepGoing method.
Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are few problems: -

- First you are comparing strings using `==` operator, which will always be false. Use `equals` method: -

  ```
  if (input.equals("y"))   // or,   if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
  ```
- Secondly, you should not use `scan.next()` method, the way you are using. Your first `scan.next` should be assigned to `input`, as your 2nd `scan.next` contains the newline: -

  ```
  System.out.println ("Do you want to process another rectangle?"); 
  // scan.next();  // Should not be here.
  String input = scan.next();
  scan.next();     // Change the order
  ```

  Or, just use `scan.nextLine()`: -

  ```
  System.out.println ("Do you want to process another rectangle?"); 
  String input = scan.nextLine();
  ```
- Third, in your `else` part, you can just invoke your `keepGoing` method again, rather than reading input there: -

  ```
  else
  {
      System.out.println("Bad input please try again!");
      return keepGoing();
  }
  ```
- Also, in your `if-else`, rather than setting the boolean values to the variables, you can directly return from there.

So, in all, you can change your `if-else if-else` to: -

```
if (input.equals("y")) {
    return true;
}
else if (input.equals("n")) {
    return false;
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Bad input please try again!");
    return keepGoing();
}
```

And then, you don't need those `boolean` variables: - `inputRead` and `result`. Just remove them. And remove the `return` statement from the end of your `method`. As it will be `unreachable code` now.

Comment: Thanks, what you've said makes sense. One thing however, when it asks if I want to spawn another rectangle, I have to enter 'y' and then 'y' again before it works, any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, because you didn't store `first scan.next()` in your input. See my 2nd point. When you read with `scan.next()`, the first one contains the `input`, and the 2nd `scan.next()` will contain the `newline`.

Comment: @AndyGault.. You should better use `scan.nextLine` to read string input. If you are doing comparison as string. See my edited post.

Answer (score 4):

`if (input == "y")`

always compare Strings with `equals()`

you need

`if ("y".equals(input))`

or

`if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) // will also allow Y`

change the other checks accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

always compare strings with .equals()

```
 if (input == "y")
```

replace to

```
 if (input.equals("y"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if two Strings are equal using `==` operator. Always, check String equality using equals method.

```
if (input == "y")
```

should be

```
if (input.equals("y"))
```

and in the rest of the places as well,

`==` operator checks if two String references point to the same String Object. equals method determines if two String objects are meaningfully equal.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
if (input.equals("y"))
{
    inputRead = true;
    result = true;

}
else if (input.equals("n"))
{
    inputRead = true;
    result = false;

}
```

Should solve the problem. Remember, objects in Java are compared by references, not by values.